# 3 dimensional closed oriented manifold with non-trivial torsion in first cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I would like to ask whether there is a 3 dimensional closed oriented manifold $M^3$ such that its first cohomology group $H^1(M^3,Z)$ has non-trivial torsion.

Comment: The first cohomology group of a space has no torsion.

Comment: Thank you. That is a simple and general answer!

Comment: You are welcome. In fact ou have an isomorphism $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong Hom(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, the universal coefficient theorem gives us an exact sequence
$$0 \to Ext(H_0(M);\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}) \to Hom(H_1(M),\mathbb{Z}) \to 0$$

Note that the $Ext$ term vanishes because $H_0(M)$ is free.  Then, as mentioned in the comments, $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}) \cong Hom(H_1(M),\mathbb{Z})$, which is why torsion vanishes.